# Linux perf not resolving symbols

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I am using Openwrt  having linux Kernel version 4.14 .

I have compiled my C++ code with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` and with debug `-g3`.  For the compiled binary and all dependent libraries ,`objdump -t`  list the symbols. `ulimit-a` output is also good, have set most of component to unlimited or a to higher value.

Executing perf with command `perf record -F 99 -p pid  --call-graph dwarf  -g` and `perf record -F 99 -p <pid>  -g`

perf report  resolves all the kernel symbols ,but NOT getting resolve the user space symbols.

Am I missing something ? How to get the user space symbols resolved?

Answer (score 4):

compiling perf tool with libelf and libdw support resolved the issue .
Able to get userspace symbols also resolved along with Kernel.